# I hope it will be vs. I hope it be

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

There is this party in August that I cannot participate. So I am writing to a friend and I want to wish/hope that it be a great event for them. Which of the following is correct?

> 1. I hope it will be a great event for you.
> 2. I hope it be a great event for you.

Also, should I use hope or wish for such context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I hope it be a great event for you.` is grammatically wrong. Replace *be* (infinitive form) with *is* (conjugated form).

These 2 are correct. I would choose the first one because the event is still somewhat far into the future.

> 1. I hope it will be a great event for you.
> 2. I hope it is a great event for you.

You can also replace *hope* by *wish* in those sentences and they mean the same thing. I would use *hope*.

Answer (score 1):

In "I hope it be", "be" is not infinitive, but subjunctive, the same as "I suggest he be the boss". It is correct although too formal, perhaps.
Used in context meaning desire

Comment: This is the correct answer. I hope + subjunctive is formal and archaic, but not wrong. Asserting it is wrong is not giving the whole picture.

Comment: @Eddie Kal Can the OP's sentense be put so: "I hope it to be a great event for you."?